# Counting ways for $12$ card-hands to contain $4$ cards in each of three suits

Tags: combinatorics

In a card deck of $52$, I want to count the ways for $12$ card-hands to contain 4 cards in each of three suits.

I thought that it'd be:

The ways of picking first suit $\to 4$

The ways of having 4 cards with this suit $\to \binom{12}4$

The ways of picking first suit $\to 3$

The ways of having 4 cards with this suit  $\to \binom{12}4$

The ways of picking first suit $\to 2$

The ways of having 4 cards with this suit $\to \binom{12}4$

So total ways is: $4\cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot \binom{13}4 ^3$.

My notes say this is incorrect but do not say why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should divide your result by $3!$ otherwise you count each acceptable hand more than one time. The total number of ways is
$$\binom{4}{3} \binom{13}4 ^3=4\binom{13}4^3.$$

Comment: Is it because doing $4\times 3\times 2$ means I "arrange" the suits?

Comment: Yes, basically you choose the set of suits in $\binom{4}{3}=4$ ways (or you exclude one of the 4 suits),

Comment: I see. There was another problem that was: "how many consist of seven cards in one suit,a nd six in another, in a 13 card hand"?  
The solution was $4\times 3\times \binom{13}{7}\times\binom{13}{6}$.  
Shouldn't I also divide by $2!$ here?

Comment: @Natash1 No because we have to distinguish the set of $7$ cards from the set of $6$ cards (their cardinalities are different).

Comment: @Natash1 Any further doubt?

Comment: No I think I understand now: highly appreciate it.